# Parenthesis error check for infix to postfix conversion Java

Tags: java, stack, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I have been working on a program for infix to postfix conversion and have everything working except that I cannot figure out where to put an error check for a missing left parenthesis. Basically the user inputs a String and the program goes to this class and converts it but I want to make sure they have entered the correct amount of parenthesis. I have tried multiple places but keep coming up with EmptyStackExceptions.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PostfixConversion {


   public static boolean precedence(char first, char second)
   {
      int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
      //find value for first
      if(first == '-' || first == '+'){
         v1 = 1;
      }else if(first == '*' || first == '/'){
         v1 = 2;    
      }//end if

      //find value for second
      if(second == '-' || second == '+'){
         v2 = 1;
      }else if(second == '*' || second == '/'){
         v2 = 2;    
      }//end if

     if(v1 < v2){
        return false;
     }//end if

     return true;
  }//end precedence method

 //converts infix expression into postfix expression
 public static String convertToPostfix(String infixExp)
  {
     String postFix = "The Postfix Expression is: ";
     Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
     char character = ' ';

     for(int i = 0; i < infixExp.length(); i++)
     {
         character = infixExp.charAt(i);

         //determine if character is an operator
         if(character == '*' || character == '-' || character == '/' || character == '+')
         {
             while(!stack.empty() && precedence(stack.peek(), character)){
                 postFix += stack.pop();
             }//end while
             stack.push(character);
         }
         else if(character == '(') //check for left parenthesis
         {
             stack.push(character);
         }
         else if (character == ')') 
         {
             while(!stack.peek().equals('(') && !stack.isEmpty()){ //add characters until left parenthesis
                 postFix += stack.pop();
             }//end while

             if(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().equals('(')){
                 stack.pop(); // pop/remove left parenthesis
             }
         }
         else
         {
             postFix += character;
         }//end if
     }//end for
     while(!stack.empty()) //add the remaining elements of stack to postfix expression
     {
         if(stack.peek().equals('('))
         {
             postFix = "There is no matching right parenthesis.";
             return postFix;
         }
         postFix += stack.pop();
     }
         return postFix;
 }//end convertToPostfix
}
```

Comment: Give an example on which you receive `EmptyStackExceptions`

Comment: @Andremoniy Err, an expression with a missing left parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to change your `while` loop to this form:

```
while (!stack.empty() && precedence(stack.peek(), character)) {
    postFix += stack.pop();
}
```

i.e. change order of expressions in `while`'s check: `stack.empty()` check should be the first.

Second fix will be addition of `"There is no matching left parenthesis."` error message here:

```
if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().equals('(')) {
   stack.pop(); // pop/remove left parenthesis
} else {
   postFix = "There is no matching left parenthesis.";
   return postFix;
}
```